# UIDatePicker shows incorrect time

Tags: swift, timezone, uidatepicker

I'm trying to set the minimumDate to the datepicker, but the datepicker adds +1 hour when showing.

I suspect that the timezone of the Datepicker is different from *firstPossibleOrderTime*.

I get this from api: 20181127151122.

Then use SwiftyDate pod to init date.

```
    DateInRegion(firstPossiblePickup, format: "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
    region: .currentIn()). 

    let datePickerFrame = UIDatePicker(frame: .zero)
    datePickerFrame.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "nb")


    print(self.firstPossibleOrderTime.date)
    print(self.firstPossibleOrderTime.date.add(28.days))

    datePickerFrame.minimumDate = self.firstPossibleOrderTime.date
    datePickerFrame.maximumDate = self.firstPossibleOrderTime.date.add(28.days)
```

How can i prevent the Datepicker from increment the time by 1 hour?

Comment: What is `firstPossibleOrderTime.date` value? How did you init it? Is it the correct value?

Comment: Can you show us what 'firstPossibleOrderTime' is ? My guess is when your timestamp comes from the server and you parse it into a date instance you are using the wrong format (eg. timezone)

Comment: I get this from api: 20181127151122.
Then uses pod to init: DateInRegion(firstPossiblePickup, format: "yyyyMMddHHmmss", region: .currentIn()).

self.firstPossibleOrderTime.date is then:
2018-11-27 15:11:22 +0000

Comment: @KristerMoen You can edit your question to add these informations to your question. Also the information which pod you are using is important thou.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that probably you are using the wrong date formatter to convert the date you are receiving from the server.
Is the time you receive from the server a string?
If it is a string, in which time zone is set?
You must take that into account before parsing it, usually servers returns a `en_US_POSIX` date string that you can parse with this date formatter.

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
        dateFormatter.isLenient = false
```

If it is not in this format you probably must take into account time zone or daylight saving.